# RichTextBox.AutoWordSelection broken?

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

I am writing a windows forms application in C# and I create a RichTextBox (via code, not the designer). I am setting the AutoWordSelection property to false, but when I highlight stuff in the box, it still jumps to the boundaries of words, plus a space. Is this a flaw in .NET or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "jumps to the boundaries of words"?  AutoWordSelection = True allows the user to double click a word and select it.  If this doesn't work then please post a code snippet and a more detailed description of what happens.

Comment: If you put the cursor in the middle of a word and drag it to the middle of another word, it should have half of both words selected. This is not the case. When you drag it to another word, it selects the entire word plus the space on the right side of the word, not just the characters you drag your mouse past.

If you want to see what I mean, just make a richtextbox, type in it, and try to highlight a group of words and you'll see that it will 'jump' to the edge of the nearest word, and not stay exactly with your mouse.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using .NET 3.5 i still have this issue.  This was reported to Microsoft and flagged as a "Wont Fix" in 2005.  This is the latest news i can find on the issue.

Here is the MS Connect bug report:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115441/richtextboxs-autowordselection-property-does-not-work-correctly#details

Here is a more recent 2010 post about another person who noticed the problem:
http://sonicflare.net/2010/01/10/shipped-bug-feature/#more-192

----------UPDATE-------------

I've made it work by placing an extra AutoWordSelection = False in the Form's Load event.

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rich = new RichTextBox();
        rich.Size = new Size(150, 50);
        rich.Text = "Ignoring a bug for five years does not make it a undocumented feature.";
        rich.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        rich.AutoWordSelection = false;
        this.Controls.Add(rich);
    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(delegate
    {
        rich.AutoWordSelection = false;
    }));
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the text boxes are created dynamically in the program. If you can imagine, every time a user adds a tab to a TabControl that I have in my form, the tab comes equipped with a RichTextBox. Can it be fixed in this case?

Comment: Perhaps try to do this in one of the tab events.  I believe the key would be to set the property on a different thread than the one it is created on.  Also note, while your drag and drop selection works on my fix, double clicking a word still selects it.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here with RichTextBox in TabControl. It didn't matter if it was created in Designer or dynamically. The solution was, as Roast suggested in the comment below his answer, to use one of the tab events. After setting `AutoWordSelection` to `False` there, the problem would intermittently return when changing tabs. What fixed that was setting it to `True` and then `False` in the tab event.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    RichTextBox1.AutoWordSelection = True
    RichTextBox1.AutoWordSelection = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I also am dynamically creating rich text boxes and had the same selection problem.  It took some doing, but I worked around it by essentially doing my own selection routine.  There is some noticeable flicker whenever my routine disagrees with the control's default selection, but it's not too bad.

I created a private integer that keeps track of the selection's starting position.  It's -1 by default.  Then I implemented a MouseDown event handler to handle the pressing of the left mouse button.  It discovers the character position at the mouse pointer and if it's not already inside the current selection, it sets the private integer to the current character position.

The MouseMove event handler then checks that the left mouse button is still pressed and updates the control's SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties, according to the saved starting position and the current character position.  Note that the starting position is always the left side of the selection, so it follows the mouse when selecting text backwards.

It gets only slightly tricky if you want to also support drag-and-drop and selection margin.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this, but with a tabbed editor with multiple RTBs. In this case, you can implement the workaround by setting the `AutoWordSelection` property to `False` in the code block that creates the RichTextBox. Like so:

```
Private Sub CreateNewRTBObject(ByVal items() As String)
    Try
        For Each s As String In items
            If Not FilePaths.Contains(s) Then
                rtb = New myRTB(s)
                rtb.AutoWordSelection = False
            End If
        Next
        tabs.SetTabWidth()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, title)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set it to ON and OFF in the SelectionChanged event.

VbNet example:

```
Private Sub SimpleRTB_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SelectionChanged
    '
    ' ----------- AUTO WORD SELECTION BUG CORRECTION 
    Me.AutoWordSelection = True
    Me.AutoWordSelection = False
    ' ------------------------------------------
End Sub
```

Comment: But this question is about C#, not VB.NET. I realize the interfaces are very similar, but all the more reason to provide an answer in the requested language.